# Validating data against a JSON object retrieved using fetch in react-native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api

I am trying to validate a string against values stored in a database to check whether that string exists there.

Here is the JSON Object being retrieved:

```json
{
  "ArrayOfJobsModel": {
    "JobsModel": [
      {
        "LongName": "WC389 - This is WC389 Job",
        "Name": "WC389"
      },
      {
        "LongName": "WC256 - The WC256 JO Description",
        "Name": "WC256"
      },
      {
        "LongName": "TT134 - The TT134 description",
        "Name": "TT134"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here I need to check whether a variable called `jobNumber` exists as a Name in the JSON object.

And here is the part of the code where I attempt to retrieve the JSON object but I am not sure how to search it.

```js
fetch('http://orhapi.azurewebsites.net/api/services/LoadJobs?type=all', { 
  method: 'GET',
  header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
}).then((response) => {
  response.json();
}).then((myJson) => {
 //not sure what to do here
}).catch((err)=>{
      alert('could not connect to server')
});

  if(this.state.numberExists){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('StockItem',{jobNumber: this.state.jobNumber});
       }
```

I need to check whether `jobNumber` exists inside `myJson` as a Name (e.g check if `jobNumber == WC256`)

Edit:
Here is an attempt I tried but I can't figure out what's wrong with it:

```js
then((responseJson) => {
                             responseJson.ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel.map((job, index)=>{
                               if(job.Name == this.state.jobNumber){
                                 this.state.numberExists;
                               }
                             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `map` method to search a term in your array of objects.

for example -

```
 let itemFound = false;
 ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel.map((job, index) => {
    if(job.Name == 'Your search string'){
      itemFound = true;
    }
 });
```

Comment: I keep on getting a network error when trying something like that. I have added in an edit above what I attempted. can you please let me know what you think?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I am getting a rejected promise error when I try including this code inside the .then

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but if you are just looking for a solution for now,

```
object = {
  "ArrayOfJobsModel": {
    "JobsModel": [
      {
        "LongName": "WC389 - This is WC389 Job",
        "Name": "WC389"
      },
      {
        "LongName": "WC256 - The WC256 JO Description",
        "Name": "WC256"
      },
      {
        "LongName": "TT134 - The TT134 description",
        "Name": "TT134"
      }
    ]
  }
};

found = false;
size = object.ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel.length;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  if(object.ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel[i].Name == 'WC256')
  {
    found = true
    break
  }
}
console.log(found)
if(found == true)
console.log(object.ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel[i].LongName)
```

Comment: Hey mate, I tried several things but for some reason I get a rejected promise whenever I try implementing anything. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Not sure. I've been using https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor to test the code, and everything seems to be working fine for this example.

Answer (score 0):

the find method on an array should be all you need to use here.

```
console.log(object.ArrayOfJobsModel.JobsModel.find( model => model.Name == 'WC256'));
```

Comment: I keep on getting a promise rejection (id: 1) when I try something like that.